# WCAG Compliance and IE11

Tags: accessibility

If I have website functionality that works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE11, (basically a keyboard trap in a form). Does that still fail compliance?  Or is the end user responsible for choosing browsers that work better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it would fail compliance. WCAG is browser agnostic and the guidelines are to be followed for all browsers. A significant number of people use JAWS as a screenreader, which is most widely used by Internet Explorer. This would be rendering the page useless for a significant number of users and would be a violation of
[Guideline 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/keyboard-operation.html).

Answer (score 1):

> If I have website functionality that works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE11, (basically a keyboard trap in a form). Does that still fail compliance?

You have to read [Understanding Conformance](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/conformance.html) to understand that this is a very complex questions

You can perfectly claim conformance based on tests done on some selected browsers, for instance those used by a company when talking about an intranet application ("*Web technologies may only need to be supported by those specific user agents and assistive technologies deployed at a company.*"). But this will give you a conformance for those browsers, and not for the other one.

So yes, this will be conform using Chrome, and not using IE11. This does not help.

> Or is the end user responsible for chosing browsers that work better?

You define your end user. If you can choose the browser used by your visitors (company intranet, touch screen kiosk, ...), then you are responsible for chosing and can set the required environment.

In any other case, if you can't choose the browser used by your visitors you have to give them a conforming version or an alternate conforming version.

You can claim conformance for a set of browsers, but as long as your website is not compatible with IE11, it will not be accessible for those users, and you can't ask them to use another browser (as they sometimes have no choice to)